# How can I improve this algorithm to prevent TLE is SPOJ submission?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem:
http://www.spoj.pl/problems/TRIP/

I wrote a solution using DP (Dynamic Programming) in C++ (code posted below). But I get TLE (Time Limit Exceeded). How can I optimize my code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
string a,b;
vector<string> v;
int dp[85][85];

void filldp()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= a.length(); i++)
        dp[i][0] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= b.length(); i++)
        dp[0][i] = 0;   

    for(int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++)
        for(int j = 1; j<= b.length(); j++)
        if(a[i-1] == b[j-1])
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1] + 1;
        else
            dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]); 
}

vector<string> fillv(int i, int j)
{
    vector<string> returnset;
    if(i == 0 || j == 0)
    {   returnset.push_back("");
        return returnset;
    }

    if(a[i-1] == b[j-1])
        { 
          vector<string> set1 = fillv(i-1,j-1);
          for(int k = 0; k < set1.size(); k++)
          { 
            returnset.push_back(set1[k] + a[i-1]);
         }  
          return returnset;
        }

    else
        {
            if(dp[i][j-1] >= dp[i-1][j])
            {
                vector<string> set1 = fillv(i,j-1);
                returnset.insert(returnset.end(), set1.begin(), set1.end());
            }

            if(dp[i-1][j] >= dp[i][j-1])
            {
                vector<string> set2 = fillv(i-1,j);
                returnset.insert(returnset.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end());
            }

            return returnset;

        }       

}

void output()
{
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << endl;   
    cout << endl;       
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    while(T--)
    {
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        v.clear();
        cin >> a >> b;
        filldp();
        v = fillv(a.length(), b.length());
        output();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My guess here is that there is a lot of passing around of data structures which can be avoided but I cannot exactly figure out how.

Comment: What's TLE?  Three-Letter Evasiveness?  You'll get more/better answers if you don't require respondents to be familiar with the jargon of a particular sub-culture.

Answer (score 5):

The first wrong thing you're doing is using cin and cout, which are terribly slow. Never use cin and cout for contest programming! I've gone from TLE to AC just by changing cin/cout to scanf/printf.

Comment: Another option is adding `ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` to your code.

Comment: could you explain me what's tle?

Comment: TLE is one of the answers that an online judge gives you. An online judge has a set of problems: you choose one of them, code a solution, and send the code. The judge compiles the solution, runs it, feeds it the input data and analyzes the output data produced by your program. Then, it gives you an answer: AC (meaning accepted) means that your solution was OK: it compiled correctly, and calculated the correct answer. TLE means that your solution was too slow: when the judge ran it, it failed to compute the solution before the time limit. You should try SPOJ (www.spoj.pl) or COJ (coj.uci.cu).

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that TLE is Time Limit Exceeded. Other common judgements are WA (Wrong Answer: your program didn't output the correct answer for the input data), CE (Compilation Error, goes without explaining), MLE (Memory Limit Exceeded: your program used too much memory) and PE (Presentation Error: your program output the correct data, but in the wrong format).

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly reduce the time of execution by taking input using `fread()` or `fread_unlocked()` (if your program is single-threaded). Locking/Unlocking the input stream just once takes negligible time, so ignore that.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int maxio=1000000;
char buf[maxio], *s = buf + maxio;

inline char getc1(void)
{
   if(s >= buf + maxio) { fread_unlocked(buf,sizeof(char),maxio,stdin); s = buf; }
   return *(s++);
}
inline int input()
{
   char t = getc1();
   int n=1,res=0;
   while(t!='-' && !isdigit(t)) t=getc1(); if(t=='-')
   {
      n=-1; t=getc1();
   }
   while(isdigit(t))
   {
     res = 10*res + (t&15);
     t=getc1();
   }
   return res*n;
}
```

This is implemented in `C++`. In `C`, you won't need to include `iostream`, function `isdigit()` is implicitly available.

You can take input as a stream of chars by calling `getc1()` and take integer input by calling `input()`.

The whole idea behind using `fread()` is to take large blocks of input at once. Calling `scanf()/printf()`, repeatedly takes up valuable time in locking and unlocking streams which is completely redundant in a single-threaded program.

Also make sure that the value of `maxio` is such that all input can be taken in a few "roundtrips" only (ideally one, in this case). Tweak it as necessary. This technique is highly effective in programming competitions, for gaining an edge over your opponent in terms of time of execution.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

when you know the max size of the number of answers it's better to use array instead of vector
because it's a lot faster than vector. 
("There is at least one such trip, but never more than 1000 different ones")

function `fillv` wastes a lot of time in the code . because it's get a lot of space in runtime and free it ( because of local space for `fillv` function) . it's better to use global answer for that.

for input and output to complete "Gandalf the Grey"'s answer , if you like to use cin and cout , it's better to use `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` ( to speed up your io runtime ) however printf and scanf is much faster than this  .

Comment: Regarding `vector` and known sizes: simply call `vector::reserve` to preallocate memory. Of course, sometimes you really want stack allocated memory, so use `std::array`.